# All scripts are loaded inside the body, not head - Meteor.js IronRouter

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

For some reason all scripts are loaded inside the body.

[image: See Image]

```
Jade:

head
  title xxx
body
  +layout

template(name='layout')
  XXX

-----
JS:

Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

I have everything set up properly. Using Meteor 1.3

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the scripts to the body is by design as of Meteor 1.3. There are open questions on the repo as to why they are currently at the start of the body and not the end.  See [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6672) and [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/6375) for discussion.